# Excel VBA If Cells.Comment fail

Tags: excel, vba

Again a question regarding comments. I want to check if a cell contains a certain comment value. I'm getting an error when running this script:

```
For AA = 0 To 200
For BB = 0 To 200
    If Worksheets("Config IO").Range("D7").offset(0, 0).Value = "1" Then
        If Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Cells(2 + AA, 9 + BB).Comment = "DI" Then
            Aantal_DI = Aantal_DI + 1
        Else
            'Nothing
        End If
    Else
        'Nothing
    End If
Next BB
Next AA
```

I have no clue what's wrong with this. I'm getting this message: this property or method is not supported by the object. This error is on the second "IF" line.

Comment: You missed one word -  `.....Cells(2 + AA, 9 + BB).Comment.Text = "DI"`.  The `Text` is just one property of the `Comment`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook New error on same line: object variable block variable with not set

Comment: Does the referenced cell contain a comment?  If it doesn't you'll get that error.

Comment: Use `If Not Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Cells(2 + AA, 9 + BB).Comment Is Nothing` to check if it contains a comment first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks that the comment exists before trying to reference the text within it.

- I've moved the first `IF` check outside the loop as it references the same cell each time.
- I also took off the `Offset(0,0)` as that offsets by 0 rows and 0 columns - the same address as the original.
- I also took off `.Value` as that's the default property of the range.

---

```
Sub Test()

    Dim AA As Long, BB As Long

    If Worksheets("Config IO").Range("D7") = "1" Then
        For AA = 0 To 200
            For BB = 0 To 200
                With Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Cells(2 + AA, 9 + BB)
                    If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                        If .Comment.Text = "DI" Then
                            Aantal_DI = Aantal_DI + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next BB
        Next AA
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
If Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Cells(2 + AA, 9 + BB).Comment = "DI" Then
```

With:

```
If Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Cells(2 + AA, 9 + BB).Comment.Text = "DI" Then
```

Comment: New error on same line: object variable block variable with not set